# Mongo DB error while running puppet script

Tags: mongodb

While running the command

```
puppet apply --verbose --debug --modulepath puppet/manifests/modules
puppet/manifests/devbox.pp
```

I get the following error

```
err:/Stage[main]/Mongo-datastore/Package[mongodb]/ensure: change from absent to present failed:Could not find package mongo-10genmongo-10gen-server
```

To fix this error I installed mongodb manually and i changed the mongodb entry in the following package as

```
name => ["mongodb-org-2.6.4.1""mongodb-org-2.6.4.1"]**

package { 
      "mongodb":

      name => ["mongo-10gen", "mongo-10gen-server"],
      ensure => installed,
      require => File['/etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo'];
    }
```

Can you please tell me why I need to manually install the package while I have already written the script to install mongo-10gen and mongo-10gen-server.

Comment: Have you tried using the puppetlabs-mongodb module? https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb

Comment: This is my /etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo file                                  [10gen]
name=10gen Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64
gpgcheck=0   Shouldn't it use the base url mentioned here and install tha mongo-10gen and mongo-10gen-server package?